# C# expression result. What is wrong?

Tags: c#, .net-core

I am trying to calculate the number of pages to be displayed for a number of items and I found this result intriguing, perhaps you can help me understand what I am doing wrong here.

```
var totalItems = 11;
var pageSize = 5;
```

**Case A.**

```
var pages = (totalItems / pageSize) + (totalItems % pageSize) > 0 ? 1 : 0;
```

**Case B.**

```
var remainder = totalItems % pageSize;
var extrapage = remainder > 0 ? 1 : 0;
var pages = (totalItems / pageSize) + extrapage;
```

So basically the `extrapage` here would be the `(totalItems % pageSize) > 0 ? 1 : 0` from Case A

**Case A** gives `pages == 1`. Why is not `3` like in Case B?

**Case B** gives `pages == 3` which is the correct answer for my case.

Comment: That's because the higher order of the _+_ operator over the logical _>_ operator. So in cas A you are asking wether the sum of _(totalItems / pageSize) + (totalItems % pageSize)_ is larger than 0. Just put correct parentheses

Comment: Wrong parenthesis placement. See "Precedence and order of evaluation": https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-language/precedence-and-order-of-evaluation?view=vs-2019

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It gives you only one page because the calculation of the number of pages is wrong.
basically in here `var pages = (totalItems / pageSize) + (totalItems % pageSize) > 0 ? 1 : 0;`
you are doing an `if` expression which will return `1` or `0`

all this code `(totalItems / pageSize) + (totalItems % pageSize)` is the if statement on your code not only the `(totalItems % pageSize)`.

so to fix it you have to split it up as the case 2 or put the second condition on parenthesis like the next:

```
var pages = (totalItems / pageSize) + ((totalItems % pageSize) > 0 ? 1 : 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

Case A return 1 because the system computes it like this:

```
var pages = ( (totalItems / pageSize) + (totalItems % pageSize) > 0 ) ? 1 : 0;
```

It sets the brackets around the whole left side and that is always bigger than zero, so it returns 1.

Set the brackets!

```
var pages = (totalItems / pageSize) + ( (totalItems % pageSize) > 0 ? 1 : 0 );
```